# Redirect to another page outside of IFrame

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have asp.net page and I have an Iframe inside of the page. In the page that I have inside of the IFrame, I have a link button and the link button will redirect to another page.

Is there a way I could redirect to another page outside of the IFrame (Redirect from the parent page instead of inside of the IFrame) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you modify the "form" to look like below:

```
<form target="_top" id="form1" action="search.aspx" method="post" name="form1">
```