# Submit a form inside fancybox and redirect the page

Tags: jquery, forms, fancybox

I am using fancybox to display a form in my page, and when the form is submitted, i see that the next page is displayed inside the fancybox itself, instead of navigating to the concerned page.

I am invoking a fancybox like this:

```
<a href="login.php" id="fancybox_iframe" title="Please Login">
<img src="login.png"></a>
```

This is the jquery code:

```
$("#fancybox_iframe").fancybox({
  'width'            : '480px',
  'height'           : '575px',
  'autoScale'        : false,
  'transitionIn'     : 'none',
  'transitionOut'    : 'none',
  'type'             : 'iframe'
});
```

I am performing some validations when the submit button in the form is clicked, and when the validations are met, the form is submitting inside the fancybox itself... but i would like the fancybox to close and submit the page to the action url.

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution from **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205187/redirect-to-another-page-outside-of-iframe)**

Just added target="_top" for the form tag and it worked well.