# How to make fancybox close after hitting "submit button"

Tags: forms, fancybox

My form comes from Hubspot and is embedded into a fancybox.

I would like the box to close as soon as the person hits "submit" but instead it redirects and stays open.

Secondly, I tried entering the code to clear the content box after submission but the old data stays in the fields after reopening.

1. How do I make the box close after they "submit"?
2. How do I code so that fields clear after each submission?

http://online.saintleo.edu/FancyBox2/FancyBox.html

In advance, thank you.  You guys/gals are great.

Comment: does your form have a callback you could use to validate if the form was successfully submitted? if so, you could use `parent.jQuery.fancybox.close()` from within such callback. How much control do you have over the form format (does your third-party provider allows you to embed your own code?) .... Additionally, you don't need to have a hidden `iframe` in your main page. Call the form directly in your link `<a class="iframe" href="form.html">` and add `type: "iframe"` to your fancybox custom script.

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting your Fancybox I found this html:

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="hsForm_bc762bf8-087a41ec-8f55-263df96f988a" class="hs-custom-form stacked hs-form" action="https://forms.hubspot.com/uploads/form/v2/206683/bc762bf8-087a-41ec-8f55-263df96f988a" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
```

It works as expected when I add `target="_top"` to it.

Your `form.html` may have a form tag. Add `target="_top"` to it.

Comment: Can you show me where?  I pasted my code below.  <body> <table width="1264px" height="100" border="0" bgcolor="#0A3D32"> <tr> <td><img src="online.saintleo.edu/main-logo.png"; width="334" height="94" /></td> <td><a class="iframe" href="#form"><img src="online.saintleo.edu/RequestInfoButton-Test.jpg"; width="127" height="36" /></a></td> </tr> </table> <div id="form" style="display:none"> <iframe height="500" src="form.html"></iframe> </div> </body> </html>

Comment: I am talking about the form inside a fancybox which gets displayed on click of "Request Info"

Comment: Okay, I will look further.

Answer (score 0):

See this link [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895450/submit-a-form-inside-fancybox-and-redirect-the-page)

Add target="_top" in form tag

```
<form target="_top">
```

Comment: Sounds easy, but I don't see a plain <form> tag.  Here is my code...  <body>
<table width="1264px" height="100" border="0" bgcolor="#0A3D32">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://online.saintleo.edu/main-logo.png" width="334" height="94" /></td>
    <td><a class="iframe" href="#form"><img src="http://online.saintleo.edu/RequestInfoButton-Test.jpg" width="127" height="36" /></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="form" style="display:none">
  <iframe height="500" src="form.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>